# Prove $f$ differentiable: $\|f(v)\| \leq M \cdot \|v\|^{N+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^m$. Assume that there exists $M\in\Bbb R$ positive such that for all $v \in \mathbb R^n$: 
$$
\|f(v)\|\leq M\cdot \|v\|^{N+1}
$$
for some natural number $N\geq 1$. Prove $f$ is differentiable at $v_0=0$. What is $Df$?

I'm a bit confused on this. I've been working through the definintion for differentiable but the additional variable N is confusing me. Does this mean I need to work through partial derivatives, etc.?

Comment: No, not partial derivatives. There simply exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ so that it holds. For example if $N = 2$ then it holds that
$$\|f(v)\|\leq M\cdot \|v\|^3.$$

Comment: Thanks for the help. So I understand the goal to prove differentiable with an equation such as you mentioned, with a constant N. Is the goal to find an N that works, and then prove differentiable?

Comment: No. The point is that a function that satisfies the given condition for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is differentiable at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

First, notice that $f(0) = 0$

Then you have

$$\frac{\|f(v)-f(0)-0\cdot v\|}{\|v\|} \leq  M \|v\|^N \to 0$$

Hence $f$ is differentiable at $0$, and $Df = 0$ at $0$